# Rails rspec helper methods not recognised in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a helper method that hides some buttons depending on user role.

```rb
#application_controller
  helper_method :current_user, :manager_can_see

def manager_can_see(company)
    #if manager can see, company owner can see as well
    if current_user
      return current_user.has_role?(:manager, company) ||
             current_user == company.user ||
             current_user.has_role?('superuser')
    end
  end
```

Then in my view I have this line:

```
<% if manager_can_see(@appliance.company) %>
...
<% end %>
```

This works when I visit that page. But it fails in rspec test saying:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `manager_can_see'
```

What can be the reason and solution to this?

Here is my test:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'admin/show', type: :view do
  before(:each) do
    @user = assign(:user, FactoryBot.create(:user))
    @company = assign(:company, FactoryBot.create(:company, user: @user))
    10.times do |i|
        FactoryBot.create(:appliance, company: @company, name: "Test object #{i}")
    end
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    @companies = Company.where(user: current_user)
    @appliance = assign(:appliance, FactoryBot.create(:appliance))
  end
  I18n.available_locales.each do |_locale|
    it 'renders attributes in <p>' do
      render
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what rails version are you using ? if 6.1 then check this: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/2481

Comment: I am using 6.0.3.5. In the discussion they say for my version there is no problem. So it should not be the case.

Comment: What is the RSpec test you are having the problem with?

Comment: Added the test in the question.

Comment: if you test views (focus) then you should stub that helper method: `allow(view).to receive(:manager_can_see).and_return(true)`